# making a profile page, with tableView and textField

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

im new in ios development and i want create a profile page with UITableView i tried Google, but i didn't find anything :( Assuming that i have 1 field (Name) on UITableView, when i click on "Edit" Button, i want the TabViewCell to became a UITextFields to let me edit the data. And then when i click the "Done" Button the UITextView became a TabViewCell again with new Value, All i can found as tutorial, is just how to delete, add or move a cell.

[image: i want something like this]

Comment: I edited your question to incorporate the image. Why did you roll it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does apple have an api for making editable forms in iOS?

No, there's no API specifically for creating editable forms, but UIKit certainly provides all the tools you'd need to create editable content of all kinds. Instead of relying on tutorials to show you the solution to every problem you need to learn how to use the API that's there to construct the user experience that you imagine. Until you do that, you won't be able to implement any original ideas.

Using a table is a reasonable way to create the form you want. Consider using a different type of cell when the user hits the Edit button. So, when Edit is tapped, reload the table content using the editable cell types instead of the normal ones. When they hit Done, record the changes and then reload again using the non-editable cell types.